# What is the effect of changing system property "user.dir"?

Tags: java

What would be the possible effects of setting the "user.dir"? Does jvm uses this? If yes then in what ways? I read the we should not be changing it, but none listed out the reasons.

Comment: In what file did you change it?

Comment: You can change it in java code using system.setProperty()

Comment: You may read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)

Answer (score 1):

Altering `user.dir` doesn't make sense because it's read-only: the working directory of your JVM process (typically, the current working directory where you run `java`).

If the value of `user.dir` is not what you want you can usually run your application from a different directory.

Comment: No `user.dir` is not a readonly property, you can change its value (try it!); but it's a non-sense to do so.

Comment: Is there any side effect of changing it ? I am not changing it, but I have a library setting that system property.